70s TV animated feature with a friendly giant and watercolor "squigglevision" style
I'm trying to identify this 70s TV animated feature. As far as I know, this was a one-off special and not a series. I think it was a fantasy/fairytale genre, and it involved a friendly giant of some kind.
It had a distinctive art style. A kind of watercolor-looking "squigglevision" style. It was way before the 90s and Dr. Katz, of course, but it had some kind of artsy crossfade from frame-to-frame that made it unlike your run-of-the-mill cell animation.

Possibly The Selfish Giant, (1972)
An animated film, with watercolour art.  Based on the story by Oscar Wilde.

A giant erects a wall to keep children out of his garden, reaping the consequences of a continuous winter. After months of winter with no other seasons in sight, spring suddenly returns when the children slip into a hole in the wall and play in the trees, except for one corner of winter where a little boy is too small to climb into the tree. The giant's heart melts at the sight and, realizing how selfish he's been, he helps the child into the tree. He then tears down the wall and tells the children it was their garden to play in. Years pass and the giant enjoys playing with the children, but never sees the one special boy he first helped. One day when he had grown old, he again sees the little boy, who appears with wounds in His hands and feet. He has come to escort the giant to His garden, which is paradise.

Watch it on Youtube.




I'll have to watch the whole thing later, but this seems pretty likely.
